# How to show count zero in mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get the number of employees that joined on a specific month. Below is my sample data.

[image]

If there are no employees that joined on a month the query should show zero like so,

[image]

I have come up with something like this but this only shows the months when there is a joinee on a specific month,

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS count,
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 1 THEN 'JAN'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 2 THEN 'FEB'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 3 THEN 'MAR'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 4 THEN 'APR'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 5 THEN 'MAY'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 6 THEN 'JUN'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 7 THEN 'JUL'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 8 THEN 'AUG'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 9 THEN 'SEP'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 10 THEN 'OCT'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 11 THEN 'NOV'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 12 THEN 'DEC'
    END AS SMonth
FROM
    Reports
GROUP BY SMonth
```

I am using ***mysql***.

***EDIT***

The Reports table has data spanning different years for e.g data from 1988,2012,2015 etc so there could be data with joinee in Jan 2015 but not in Jan 2018

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: MySQL version? Or MariaDB?

Comment: MYSQL VERSION IS 5.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  a month sequence  and mananeg for null value

```
SELECT 
    sum(case when startDate is null then 0 else 1 end)  AS count,
    CASE
        WHEN t.mon_num = 1 THEN 'JAN'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 2 THEN 'FEB'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 3 THEN 'MAR'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 4 THEN 'APR'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 5 THEN 'MAY'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 6 THEN 'JUN'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 7 THEN 'JUL'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 8 THEN 'AUG'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 9 THEN 'SEP'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 10 THEN 'OCT'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 11 THEN 'NOV'
        WHEN t.mon_num = 12 THEN 'DEC'
    END AS SMonth
FROM  (
        select  1 mon_num
        union
        select  2 
        union
        select  3 
        union
        select  4 
        union
        select  5 
        union
        select  6 
        union
        select  7 
        union
        select  8 
        union
        select  9 
        union
        select  10 
        union
        select  11 
        union
        select  12 
        
) t

LEFT JOIN Reports ON t.mon_num = MONTH(startDate) 
GROUP BY SMonth
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217775/discussion-between-ayub-ahmed-and-scaisedge).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217778/discussion-between-bisoux-and-scaisedge).

Comment: @Bisoux  i have seen the last comment in chat ..  if the condition  " 'and teamName = 'XX'' is based on column in  report  table you should manage for null value also for this column...

Answer (score 2):

Something like that may fit. But you can also get month from date functions.

```
SELECT 
    date_table.dt,
    MONTHNAME(date_table.dt) SMonth,
    COUNT(r.startDate) AS count
FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            DATE(CONCAT(1970 + y1.num + y2.num*10, "-", mnth.num, "-01")) dt
        FROM
            (SELECT 1 num UNION ALL SELECT 2 num UNION ALL SELECT 3 num UNION ALL SELECT 4 num UNION ALL SELECT 5 num UNION ALL SELECT 6 num UNION ALL SELECT 7 num UNION ALL SELECT 8 num UNION ALL SELECT 9 num UNION ALL SELECT 10 num) y1
        CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT 1 num UNION ALL SELECT 2 num UNION ALL SELECT 3 num UNION ALL SELECT 4 num UNION ALL SELECT 5 num UNION ALL SELECT 6 num UNION ALL SELECT 7 num UNION ALL SELECT 8 num UNION ALL SELECT 9 num UNION ALL SELECT 10 num) y2
        CROSS JOIN
            (SELECT 1 num UNION ALL SELECT 2 num UNION ALL SELECT 3 num UNION ALL SELECT 4 num UNION ALL SELECT 5 num UNION ALL SELECT 6 num UNION ALL SELECT 7 num UNION ALL SELECT 8 num UNION ALL SELECT 9 num UNION ALL SELECT 10 num UNION ALL SELECT 11 num UNION ALL SELECT 12 num) mnth
    ) date_table
LEFT JOIN 
    Reports r on FORMAT_DATE(r.startDate, "%Y-%m-01") = date_table.dt
WHERE
    date_table.dt BETWEEN "1991-07-24" AND NOW()
GROUP BY
    date_table.dt
ORDER BY
    date_table.dt
;
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is working too, you should have mysql latest version.

```
with recursive cte (n) as (
select '2012-01-01' 
union all 
select n+interval 1 month
from cte 
where n < '2012-12-01'
) select count(emp.empno) as total,date_format(cte.n,'%M') as Month
 from cte left join emp
 on  date_format(cte.n,'%M')  = date_format(emp.hiredate,'%M') 
 group by cte.n ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `coalesce(count(*), 0)`  or `ifnull(count(*), 0)` in your query.

```
SELECT 
    coalesce(COUNT(*), 0) AS count,
    CASE
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 1 THEN 'JAN'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 2 THEN 'FEB'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 3 THEN 'MAR'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 4 THEN 'APR'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 5 THEN 'MAY'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 6 THEN 'JUN'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 7 THEN 'JUL'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 8 THEN 'AUG'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 9 THEN 'SEP'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 10 THEN 'OCT'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 11 THEN 'NOV'
        WHEN MONTH(startDate) = 12 THEN 'DEC'
    END AS SMonth
FROM
    Reports
GROUP BY SMonth
```

Comment: This one gives the same result as my own query i.e. if there are no records on that month zero is not shown